# What are alternatives to the verb “study” (in the meaning of “research”)?

Tags: writing, synonyms, formality

When writing scientific discussions (articles, book chapters, reports, ...), I frequently feel short on synonyms of the verb **study**, which I use extensively in sentences such as *“in the next section, we study the influence of ... on ...”*. The alternatives I frequently use include **investigate**, **research**, **look into**, and **shed light into** (with a slightly different meaning). What I like in **study** and its synonyms is its rather generic meaning: it does not actually specify the type of research being done, which is desirable in some occasions.

As a consequence, I am looking for other alternatives to this verb, or constructs similar to the example quoted above (*“in the next section, we study the influence of ... on ...”*), to improve my writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these might work:
1. Pay attention to
2. Consider
3. Brainstorm
4. Canvass
5. Scrutinize
6. Discuss
7. Contemplate
8. Survey

Comment: I like *scrutinize*.

Answer (score 1):

The alternatives I can think of are:

- analyze
- check out (informal)
- cram (informal)
- explore
- hit the books (informal)
- inquire into
- inspect
- learn
- look at
- read
- review

Comment: I like *inspect* and *inquire into*. I want to avoid informal alternatives at all cost, and thus wonder: isn't **look at** somewhat informal?

Comment: Oh, another question and a comment: **1.** for *read*, NOAD has “study (an academic subject) at a university”, which is incoherent with the idea of research (as opposed to learning)? **2.** *review* has a different, established meaning of “comprehensive survey”, which I want to avoid here

Comment: _Look at_ doesn't sound informal to me. The NOAD doesn't report it is informal; the example I find on that dictionary is _a committee is looking at the financing of PBS_.

Comment: _Read_ is also used to mean _to discover information by reading it in a written or printed source_: _I read about the course in a magazine_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, in that sense, I don't think it's appropriate in academic writing

Comment: @FX_: You can also understand it with a broad meaning: If you are searching something in a written (or printed) source, you are reading the source to find what you are looking for. If a teacher is going to explain something using a book as reference, s/he can say _today we will read about […]_; it doesn't mean that reading the book is the main activity being done, nor does it mean that reading the book will be effectively done (the book can be used as reference to say to the students which part of the book they need to study).

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to convey how the next section achieves something. For example, the next section ..

- introduces
- surveys
- analyzes
- concludes
- compares
- collects
- defines
- hypothesizes
- assumes

something about your field of study.

Answer (score 0):

- Examine
- Review
- Consider
- Appraise
- Probe
- Scrutinise